# How can I make jtextarea resizable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextarea

I did 2 jtextarea in one panel. When I click a button which makes invisible first jtextarea the other jtextarea shift up but its size does not change. But I want it shift up and change its size.(its height will be more) .
I use **`setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));`**  or I Use **`unresizable`** margin.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Use proper LayoutManager e.g. vertically oriented BoxLayout.

Comment: Are you able to post some of your code to better show us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) it helps you

Comment: thanks for reply , but I dont know how can I use layoutmanager , I should search it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setRows` method and call revalidate on the panel.

For example,

Before hiding textarea1,

```
textarea1.setRows(2);
textarea2.setRows(3);
```

After hiding textarea1,

```
panel.removeAll();
textarea2.setRows(5);
panel.add(textarea2); 
panel.revalidate();
```

Comment: I try it now and I will be back to you soon

Comment: The proper way to use `LayoutManager`

Comment: When I set rows , it makes scroll on the jtextare but its size does not change

Comment: Are you using a scroll pane??

Comment: I think then your panel is too small. Try resizing the window. Better use a layout manager instead.

Comment: Add the code you have tried, in the question. That would help.

Comment: Panel is small but when I hide the first jtextarea , 2. jtextarea shift up but its size does not change , and there is more place under it.

Comment: use `panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout())`, this will remove the scrollbars

Comment: @DeepakMishra when I delete the scrollbars , It will be issue because when I have more than 5 rows I cant see the others rows ?

Comment: I'm not asking you to remove the scrollbar. just use flow layout. and use preferred size on the panel. Get the layouts right and it will be fixed.